# margin parameter not working in Owl Carousel slider magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, slider, owl-carousel

> Please check my code,if anyone have any idea please guide me -

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#discounts-offers": {
            "OwlCarousel": {
                "autoPlay": true,
                "items": 4,
                "lazyLoad":true,
                "navigation":true,  
                "pagination" : false,
                "loop":true,
                "margin":30,
                "itemsDesktop" : [1150,3],
                "itemsTablet" : [767,1],
                "itemsMobile:": [480,1],
                "navigationText": ["<div class='prev-btn'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i></div>", "<div class='next-btn'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></div>"]
            }
        }               
    }
```

> Here i want to add margin to slider,but it's not reflecting any changes.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran there is no Console error

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I am also facing the similar situation